# Ruby Regular Expression for Parcelify (Shopify)

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex in Ruby for a shipping query.

If postcodes match MK1 - MK10, MK19, MK43, MK46 or MK77, then allow it. 
If postcodes match NN1 - NN7, NN12, NN13, NN29 or NN77, then allow it.
If postcodes match MK11 - MK18 then don't allow it.

My trouble is that in the UK our postcodes are a bit funny where you can put MK1 1TS and MK11TS and they're considered the same. By not allowing MK11, MK11TY could be misread as MK11.

I've written a regex below, and so far it will disallow MK111TS and MK11\s1TS, and allow MK1\s1TS but not MK11TS. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've only tested this for MK11 so far.

```
^((?!MK11\d).)*$&^((?!MK11\s\d).)*$|(MK(1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10 ))|(MK19)|(MK43)|(MK46)|(MK77)|(NN1)|(NN2)|(NN3)|(NN4)|(NN5)|(NN6)|(NN7)|(NN12)|(NN13)|(NN29)|(NN77)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strip spaces, then match.

Comment: What is the format of a UK Postcode?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 The [Wikipedia article on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) actually includes a regular expression definition, which is pretty amazing: `^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$`

Comment: Thanks but doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to filter only for certain postcodes, not find out how to write all postcodes

Comment: In my answer I assumed that "If postcodes match MK11 - MK18 then don't allow it." could be replaced by "If postcodes don't match these, then don't allow it." Is that an appropriate assumption?

Comment: Hi Cary, yes that's an accurate assumption :) I will reply to your answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = /
    (?:                                     # begin non-capture group           
      MK                                    # match characters
      (?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|19|43|46|77)  # match one of the choices
      |                                     # or
      NN                                    # match characters
      (?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|12|13|29|77)         # match one of the choices
    )                                       # end non-capture group
    (?![^\sA-Z])                            # do not match a space or cap letter
    /ix                                     # case indifferent and free-spacing
                                            # regex definition mode
```

This is conventionally written

```
r = /(?:MK(?:1|2|...|10|19|...|77)|NN(?:1|2|...|7|12|13|29|77))(?![^\sA-Z])/i

"MK4 abc def MK11MK19ghi NN6 jkl NN13 NN29NN77".scan(r)
   # => ["MK4", "NN6", "NN13", "NN29", "NN77"]
```

`"MK11"` is not matched because `"11"` is not in the list. `"MK19"` is not matched because it is followed by a character that is neither a space nor a capital letter.

Alternatively, one could write

```
s = (['MK'].product(%w{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 19 43 46 77}).map(&:join) +
     ['NN'].product(%w{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 13 29 77}).map(&:join)).join('|')
  # => "MK1|MK2|...|MK10|MK19|MK43|MK46|MK77|NN1|NN2|...|NN7|NN12|NN13|NN29|NN77"
r = /(?:#{s})(?![^\sA-Z])/i
  #=> /(?:MK1|MK2|...|MK10|MK19|...|MK77|NN1|NN2|...|NN7|NN12|NN13|NN29|NN77)(?![^\sA-Z])/
```

If the remainder of the postal code is to be included in the regex, perhaps something like the following could be done.

```
suffixes = %w|ES AB CD EF|.join('|')
  #=> "ES|AB|CD|EF"
```

Then replace `(?![^\sA-Z])/x` with the following.

```
\s?             # optionally match a space
(?:#{suffixes}) # match a valid suffix in a non-capture group
(?!\S)          # do not match a non-whitespace char (negative lookahead)
/ix             # case-indifferent and free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note the negative lookahead is satisfied if the suffix is at the end of the string.

Comment: I like how you wrote the regex in the top part of your answer, I will be doing it like this when I struggle to get it right or when it is a long regex.

Comment: Hi Cary, great answer and very easy to understand. My question however must not have been as this is only partly where I'm trying to get to. The standard format of a UK postcode is either (for example) MK131ES or MK13 1ES, either one must be accepted whether or not there is white space in the middle. As above it is written as 2 letters (donate area of UK), 1 or 2 numbers (donates locality within that area), then 1 number and 2 letters (donating a specific group of houses within that locality). I have edited to also accept lowercase (just in case), I have edited my question, thank you.

Comment: @RoanFourie, yes, the free-spacing mode makes the regex definition self-documenting, but there is a potential "gotcha" with its use: it strips out spaces. Whereas `'cat dog'[/t d/] #=> 't d'`, `'cat dog'[/t g/x] #=> nil`. That's because the latter is equivalent to `'cat dog'[/tg/]`. You need to use `/t\sg/`, `/t[ ]g/` or a non-breaking space.

Comment: Thanks Cary, that is very useful, I understand. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: I added something to the end of my answer to address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have written the following to match the postcodes format exactly:

```
#format: Area Code, Localities accepted, whitespace (MKor not), any digit, any single character, any single character
    ((MK|mk|Mk|mK)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|19|43|46|77)\s\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) #with whitespace
    |
    ((MK|mk|Mk|mK)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|19|43|46|77)\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) #without whitespace
    |
    ((NN|nn|Nn|nN)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|12|13|29|77)\s\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) #with whitespace
    |
    ((NN|nn|Nn|nN)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|12|13|29|77)\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) #without whitespace
```

This works for my purposes, I got here using Cary's answer, which has been extremely helpful. Thank you and have marked up.